# XOR a plain text with cipher text to retrieve the key (C1 XOR P1=K, P1 XOR K=C1)

Tags: encryption, xor

Let us consider the plain text `This is a known Message!` and the cipher text `a469b1c502c1cab966965e50425438e1bb1b5f9037a4c159`. The cipher text is the encryption of the plain text.

Does any one know of any good examples of `C1 XOR P1 = K`?

I tried converting plain text to hexadecimal and then both `p1` and `c1` to binary to `XOR` them. It does not seem to work that way. Once I get the binary, I convert it back to hexadecimal.  I am pretty sure I did it correctly but I don't get the correct key. Does anyone have any advice on that?

What I am looking for is some better examples of `XOR`ing. I do not think I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hex is a representation of bytes for human consumption. When doing XOR you should perform it on the binary data. That means *encoding* the plaintext using a character set (likely US-ASCII in this case) and *hex decoding* the ciphertext.

Once you have two byte arrays you can XOR each byte with the byte at the same index.

The *key stream* is probably random binary data, so you can *hex encode* the key to take a better look at it. If you only see sensible results between 0x20 (space) and 0x7E then it is probably ASCII text and you could perform *character-decoding* instead.

Comment: And no, this is a practice assignment, we're not here to perform these operations for you.

Comment: Finally solved it. I was trying to decode key into ascii once i had it in binary. So that was screwing me up. So after XORing C1 and p1 that gave me key in binary. Then I XORed binary key with c2 binary which gave me p2 then convert p2 to ascii to get the message. Thanks for the help!